# Query to find total records inserted in a range of dates

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am using SQL Server 2008 R2 and trying to find total records inserted between a range of dates grouped by insertdate. Since my insertdate contains hour,min and sec, all the records are being counted individually with same date but different time.
I want to keep the time information in my database but only in the query, I want to group by date omitting time.

```
@Created Date                TotalRegistration
 2014-10-20 14:40:47.757             1
 2014-10-20 12:27:27.923             1
 2014-10-20 12:25:25.613             1
```

should be

```
 @Created Date                TotalRegistration
 2014-10-20                          3
```

This is what I tried. Any suggestion will be really appreciated.
Thank You

```
Select Insertdate, COUNT(Insertdate) as TotalDailyRegistration from Customer where Insertdate between '2014-10-01 00:00:00.001' and '2014-11-08 23:59:59.743' group by Insertdate
```

Update: Followed Lamak's suggestion and it worked out fine. Since the dates were not ordered correctly, I also added order by CONVERT(DATE,Insertdate) after group by and its perfect.

Comment: @Created date has a timestamp component that needs to be dropped.  Cast the field to a true "DATE" Field and you should be able to group correctly.

Answer (score 4):

It should be better to just group by the date part of your column:

```
SELECT  CONVERT(DATE,Insertdate) InsertDate, 
        COUNT(Insertdate) as TotalDailyRegistration 
FROM Customer 
WHERE Insertdate >= '20141001' 
AND InsertDate < '20141002' 
GROUP BY CONVERT(DATE,Insertdate)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just try this:

```
create table #test( createdDate datetime,totalRegistration int)
insert into #test values('2014-10-20 14:40:47.757',1)
insert into #test values('2014-10-20 12:27:27.923',1)
insert into #test values(' 2014-10-20 12:25:25.613',1)
select *From test
Select convert(nvarchar(10),createdDate,103), sum(totalRegistration) as TotalDailyRegistration
```